# OPNET , The application has failed to start because COREDLL.dll was not found

Tags: dll

I'm trying to modify the standard model in OPNET (install OPNET in win XP) and I have omitted the `stdmod` in preference `Network simulation Repositories`. However, when I want to run my project, i get this error :

```
"The application has failed to start because MSVCR90.dll was not found. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem"
```

and then I add `MSVCR90.dll` from `...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\dll\x86`. the error changed to:

```
"The application has failed to start because COREDLL.dll was not found. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem"
```

I searched a lot but I cannot found anything useful. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you very much...

Comment: Wrong version, you copied one that can only work on Windows CE (aka Windows Mobile).  You can't copy it either.  Use [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019667) to find installers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and response. sorry i done this and now i receive new error :(                      



{    R6034
    An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.Please contact the application support team for more information.}

I cannot understand what's wrong? can you pleas explain what is the problem. Thanks. @Hans

Comment: I already told you that you cannot just copy the file.  Run the installer.